# How to remove and array element and add it to the last index - C#

Tags: c#, arrays

How can i remove an array item and get it back to the last array index?

Now i want to **REMOVE** `"id2"` in the list and get it back to the last index.

```
string[] ids = new string { "id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5"};
```

Comment: Quick solution: ids = ids.ToList().Remove("id2").Add("id2").ToArray();

Comment: There are tons of way to do that.....Simple search would have got you the answer

Comment: Although I think the duplicate fits the title, the answers are not very helpful in this case.

Comment: i have found just how to delete an array item but i don't find anything that restores back an item to the last index.

Comment: If you're doing that an awful lot, it might be best to consider some other kind of container type (or even a linked list).

Comment: @MatthewWatson Im not expert C# and i still dont really have any idea about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array is not a list where you can add or remove elements just that easy. Use a `List<T>` for that if you want to do it easy.

For your current question, this would do:

```
string idToRemove = 1;

string lastValue = ids[idToRemove];

for (int i = idToRemove + 1; i < ids.Length; i++)
{
    ids[i - 1] = ids[i];
}

ids[ids.Length - 1] = lastValue;
```

It remembers the index of the element to 'remove'. It remembers it, then replaces every element after it with its next version. In the end it sets the last item value.

Comment: It means that the indexes are not automatically arranged and you have to set it manually? Now i get it.

Comment: Indeed, if you want that, use a list.

Comment: OK sure your information help a lot.